# Could not get into docker container's bash: hydra container is restarting

Tags: docker, hydra

Using [this documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/hydra/):

1. I've pulled the `vimagick/hydra` docker image
2. Created `docker-compose.yml` file in `~/Soft/docker/` folder:

   ```
   hydra:
     image: vimagick/hydra
     command: sleep infinity
     volumes:
       - ./data:/data
     working_dir: /data
     restart: unless-stopped
   ```
3. Installed `docker-compose`
4. Executed: `docker-compose up -d
   Starting docker_hydra_1 ... done`
5. Executed: `docker-compose exec hydra bash
   Error response from daemon: Container ecf710f3f9526cf598c4a15a485fbfc3790a36e5f8b989820a157ba5453fc24f is restarting, wait until the container is running`

`docker ps` gives:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                NAMES
ecf710f3f952        vimagick/hydra         "bash sleep infinity"   20 hours ago        Restarting (126) 20 seconds ago                        docker_hydra_1
93b5c43c6952        vulnerables/web-dvwa   "/main.sh"              39 hours ago        Up 23 minutes                     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   dvwatest


$ docker exec -it ecf bash
Error response from daemon: Container ecf710f3f9526cf598c4a15a485fbfc3790a36e5f8b989820a157ba5453fc24f is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

I see that `docker-compose.yml` file contains `restart: unless-stopped` record. But why is it documented so and how to use this container when I could not connect to it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your [`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/vimagick/dockerfiles/blob/master/hydra/docker-compose.yml) as follow:

```
hydra:
  image: vimagick/hydra
  entrypoint: sleep
  command: infinity
  volumes:
    - ./data:/data
  working_dir: /data
  restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!